# Return an array and a variable together in main function

Tags: java, arrays, return, return-value, return-type

I have a function like that

```
Class Return_two{
     public static void main(String args[]){
     int b=0;// Declare a variable
     int a []= new int[3];// Declare an array [both are return at the end of the user define function fun()]
      Return_two r=new Return_two();
       int result_store= r.fun(a,b);//where should I store the result meaning is it a normal variable or an array where I store the result?
   }
 public int [] fun (int[] array,int var)//may be this is not a good Return type to returning an array with a variable so what will be change in return type? 
 {    
      for(int counter=0;counter <array.length;counter++)
      { var=var+counter;
       }
       return( array,var);// Here how could I return this two value in main function?
   }
  }
```

Now, here lies my question. I want to return an array with a variable as I written above.But as I know one can return a array or a variable but not both. Or one can return one or more variable make those variable as a array element. But how can one return an array with an variable in main function?

Comment: Create an object wrapping both

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly.

Comment: b is not array !

Comment: orf try using Pair, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pair-class-in-java/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create multiple values, wrap them in an object.

(I'm not able to come up with a meaningful name from what you have posted)

```
class Result {
    private int[] a;
    private int b;

   public Result(int[] a, int b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
   }
   //Getters for the instance variables
   public int[] getA() {
      return a;
   }
   public int getB() {
       return b;
   }
}
```

At the end of `fun`

```
return new Result(array, var);
```

Some best practices:

1. Don't declare variable names with same name as a parameter (`a` in `fun`)
2. In the above `Result` class, better to create copies on the array `a` to avoid mutations outside the class.
3. If possible, don't use arrays and use a `List` (this would give you a lot of flexibility)

**EDIT:**

Your caller will look like

```
 Return_two r=new Return_two();
 Result result = r.fun(a, b); 
 result.getA();//Do whatever you want to do with the array
 result.getB();//Do whatever you want to do with that variable
```

With your current version of the (modified) code, why do you want to return the array since it is *same* as what you pass to the `fun` method? Returning only the computed `var` will work for you (and hence the return type can simply be `int`).

You can also achieve what you do in `fun` in one line

```
return (array.length * (array.length - 1)) / 2;
```

Comment: Here you create a class name Result.Then create a constructor of this class which take two argument one is array and another is a normal variable. Then you define two separate function  `getA()` and `getB()` and return them. But in my Program I have only one function fun which can return an array as well as a variable. Is that possible? I edit my question for better understanding.

Comment: I know returning that array is not necessary but I want to know the method that how can I return an array and a variable together.

Comment: It is not possible to return more than one value from a function

Answer (score 1):

```
Wrap these properties into a object, say 

    Public class FunModel
    {
        public int[] a;
        public int b;
    }

then you can return an instance of `FunModel`.

Or

you can use `Tuples`

------------------
Futher Explanation
 ------------------
```

The return type here should be a model. 
This model should have all that you want to return as properties.
 You can return this model from your method.

```
    public class FunModel
    {
        public int[] a;
        public int b;

        public FunModel(int[] a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
```

And the method should return a instance of this model.

```
public class ReturnTwo {

            public static void main(String args[]){
                int b=0;
                int a []= new int[3];
                ReturnTwo returnTwo = new ReturnTwo();
                FunModel funModel =  returnTwo.fun(a,b);
                //other processing
            }

            public FunModel fun (int[] array,int tempVar)
            {
                FunModel temp = new FunModel(array,tempVar);
                for(int counter=0;counter <array.length;counter++)
                {
                    temp.b = temp.b + counter;
                }
                return temp;// you return the model with different properties
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't get it.. plz explain more